# Fatal error "Zend_Uri_Http" not found

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, patches

For past couple of year my website work fine. From today morning display fatal error `"Zend_Uri_Http" not found`. I don't know what's issues.

I tried to updated patch files also. I think that issue came from security patch. Because two days before i receive some error mail from website(Security patch issue like that).

Please give some suggestion how to recover my website. Website and admin panel also blocked. I forgot the magento version also.

Comment: Does this file exist /lib/Zend/Uri/Http.php

Comment: check the autoloader and make sure it reads the correct file. If the file is not found, it is either, because the wrong file is searched for or the include_path is wrong. Or the autoloader doesn't do anything.

Comment: hmm php Update to >=5.5 maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Check the autoloader and make sure it: **reads the correct file.**

If the file is not found, it is either, because:

1. **The wrong file is searched for**
2. **The include_path is wrong.**
3. **The autoloader doesn't do anything.**